# Complexity of the $(3,2)_s$ SAT problem?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, np-hardness, sat

Let define the $(3,2)_s$ SAT problem : Given $F_3$, a satisfiable 3-CNF formula, and $F_2$, a 2-CNF formula ($F_3$ and $F_2$ are defined on the same variables). Is $F_3 \wedge F_2$ satisfiable?

What is the complexity of this problem ? (Has it been studied before ?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This problem is NP-complete.

Let $\varphi$ be an arbitrary CNF formula (an instance of SAT).  Consider $\varphi \lor y$, where $y$ is a fresh variable; obviously, this formula is satisfiable (you can simply set $y$ to true).  Now convert $\varphi \lor y$ to 3-CNF, using any standard method, and let $\psi$ denote the result.  Note that $\psi$ is a satisfiable 3-CNF formula, so we can let $F_3 = \psi$.  Now, let $F_2 = \neg y$.  Notice that $F_3 \land F_2$ is satisfiable if and only if $\varphi$ is.  Therefore, the $(3,2)_s$ SAT problem is at least as hard as SAT.  Also, it is clearly no harder than SAT.  Therefore, it is exactly as difficult as SAT.

Comment: Tks @D.W, quite convincing.

Comment: You should just reduce from 3SAT instead of from SAT.

Comment: @TysonWilliams, yup, sure, we could do that too.  Is there any sense in which reducing from 3SAT would be better?   It doesn't seem to make any significant difference either way, as far as I can see.  Reducing from 3SAT doesn't seem to make the reduction any simpler.  Even if $\varphi$ is a 3-CNF formula, $\varphi \lor y$ won't be, so you still need to convert to 3-CNF either way.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Good point.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a paper by Porshen and Speckenmayer : [Satisfiability of mixed Horn formulas](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X07000327) which shows that even when $F_3$ is Horn, the problem of deciding the satisfiability of $F_3 \wedge F_2$ is NP-complete.

Comment: Actually, as far as I understand, by Schaefer's dichotomy theorem, even when $F_3$ is XOR-3-SAT, it must be NP-complete. Same for when $F_3$ is monotone (and therefore trivially satisfiable). The reduction is known without having to refer to Schaefer's theorem, though.

Comment: Good point, you are right.