# Complexity of the Complete (3,2) SAT problem?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, complexity-classes, sat

A complete $k$-CNF formula is a $k$-CNF formula which contains all clauses of size $k$ or lower it implies.

Deciding the satisfiability of a complete $k$-CNF formula is clearly a tractable problem since a $k$-CNF formula is satisfiable as long as it does not contain the empty clause. What happens when it is mixed with a 2-CNF formula?

Let define the Complete (3,2) SAT problem : Given $F_3$, a complete 3-CNF formula, and $F_2$, a (complete) 2-CNF formula ($F_3$ and $F_2$ are defined on the same variables). Is $F_3 \wedge F_2$ satisfiable?

What is the complexity of this problem ?

(The question is different as in the post [Complexity of the (3,2)s SAT problem?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18379/complexity-of-the-3-2-s-sat-problem) where it concerned non complete formulas.)

Comment: It does not matter whether $F_2$ is complete or not, as you can compute the completion of a 2-CNF in polynomial time.

Comment: True, for $F_2$, it doesn't matter.

Comment: What is "all the $k'$-clauses" with respect to $k$ ?

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi A $k'-$clause is a clause containing exactly $k'$  literals with $k'\le k$ : "all the $k'-$clause" means all clauses of size $k$ or lower that the $k-$CNF formula implies.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi Tks for your comment, I edit the post to clarify the point.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Another question, before trying to find a reduction, what is the complexity of checking if a $k$-CNF formula is complete? (if you know it)

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi I would say it is NP-complete since a complete $k$-CNF is satisfiable as long as it doesn't contain the empty cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the standard reduction from 3-coloring to SAT: for each vertex $v \in V$ we introduce three variables, $v_R,v_G,v_B$, add a clause $(v_R \vee v_G \vee v_B)$, and clauses $(\lnot v_R \vee \lnot v_G)$, $(\lnot v_R \vee \lnot v_B)$, and $(\lnot v_G \vee \lnot v_B)$. Then for each edge $(u,v) \in E$ we add clauses $(\lnot v_R \vee \lnot u_R)$, $(\lnot v_G \vee \lnot u_G)$, and $(\lnot v_B \vee \lnot v_B)$.

Observe that the clauses of size 3 in the resulting CNF are disjoint, and therefore the CNF consisting of them is complete. Therefore deciding the satisfiability of $F_3 \wedge F_2$, where $F_3$ is a complete 3-CNF formula and $F_2$ is a 2-CNF formula is an NP-complete problem.

Comment: Quite convincing, thank you !